# Help check my proof of Dini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Dini's Theorem:**
Let $f_n:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be a sequence of functions. If $f_n$ is continuous for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is monotone, and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges pointwise to a continuous function. Then $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly convergent.

I just came up with my own proof. But I'm not sure whether it's valid. Need check.

*My proof:*
Suppose $f_n\to f$ pointwise. And WLOG we suppose $\forall n\in\Bbb N,~\forall x\in [a,b],~f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$. Let $\epsilon>0$.

- Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, it is uniformly continuous. Then $\exists \delta_f>0,~\forall x_1,~x_2\in [a,b],~|x_1-x_2|<\delta_f\Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon/3$.
- Choose $P_1=a$, we begin our story at this point. Since $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges pointwise, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(P_1)=f(P_1)$. Then $\exists N>0,~\forall n\in \Bbb N,~n\geq N\Rightarrow |f_n(P_1)-f(P_1)|<\epsilon/3$.
- For the $N$ above, by hypothesis we know that $f_N$ is continuous, thus again uniformly continuous. Then $\exists \delta_{f_N}>0,~\forall x_1,~x_2\in [a,b],~|x_1-x_2|<\delta_{f_N}\Rightarrow |f_N(x_1)-f_N(x_2)|<\epsilon/3$.

Combine the above three, let $\delta=\min\{\delta_f,~\delta_{f_N}\}$, we have $\forall x\in [a,b],~|x-P_1|<\delta\Rightarrow |f_N(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. We have shown that on the closed interval $[a,a+\delta/2]$, $f_N$ is sufficiently closed to the target function $f$ within the error less than $\epsilon$, and the all term after $N$ is certainly within this range due to the monotonicity. We called the point $a+\delta/2$ by $P_2$.

Now, split the interval $[a,b]$ into evenly spaced subinteveral with length $\delta/2$. Recursivly apply the exactly same argument to the point $P_k$, we know that the the $f_N$ on the interval $[P_k,P_{k+1}]$ is sufficiently closed to the target function $f$ within the error less than $\epsilon$, where $P_{k+1}=P_k+\delta/2$. Since the number of steps we need is finite. So it is true for whole $[a,b]$, and the proof is done.

Comment: Isn't the WLOG a part of the assumption? (I mean the theorem assumes that the sequence is monotone).

Comment: @yanko It means "increasing" sequence of functions. And I just found that it is not strictly required in my proof; only monotone is OK.

Comment: Ah ok. Right, I didn't see anything wrong then. Seems good.